# linker option, sum of path too long?

Tags: c, windows, makefile, linker, iar

I have to migrate an IAR project to Eclipse IDE and GCC compiler.
For that, I do the process step by step, and the first step is to use Eclipse + makefile and IAR compiler.

The compilation is not a problem, I have object files, the problem is during the link, the linker raise a problem:

> IAR ELF Linker V7.10.3.6832/W32 for ARM
>      Copyright 2007-2014 IAR Systems AB.
>   Fatal error[Li001]: could not open file
>             "C:\tunk\src\Sources\mirtic_meta_data\mirtic_meta_data.o"

If I change the order of link files, it's not the same file which raises the error. But each time, a letter is missing in the path, and it's the same letter: "r"

here, the file should be in directory "trunk" not "tunk".
I checked, the path is correct when it sent to the linker.

Apparently, it's Windows which can't handle many path. But I don't know how to solve my problem (I tried to put the project near "C:", with no result).
I know there is a solution, because with IAR workbench, I can build a binary file.

Comment: Just a thought, but have you tried CMake?

Comment: @rubenvb No I haven't, but I don't think this solve my problem. The makefile generated by CMake should send all object files to the linker, and the problem will be raised again, no ?

Comment: Is your `Makefile` correct? Does it spell `trunk` correctly? If you run the `Makefile` in a command-line environment and look at the output of each command, is it correct everywhere? Does the command-line build fail at the same place?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I tried to compile again, this is the error:
could not open file "C:\FW_Mirtic\trunk\src\Sources\mirtic_teat_roi\mirtic_track_roi_param.o" and this is the given path:  "C:\FW_Mirtic\trunk\dev_tools\../src/Sources/mirtic_treat_roi/mirtic_track_roi_param.o" Now it's not "trunk" but "mirtic_treat_roi" which becomes "mirtic_teat_roi"

Comment: have you tried to rename the path to "C:\tunk\src\So..." without the r to see if another letter will disappear ?

Comment: There's most likely something wrong with the makefile, not with Eclipse or how paths are handled. Either skip the makefile completely and create the Eclipse project from scratch. Or try to recreate the makefile from scratch, one step at a time.

Comment: CMake puts the commandlines in "response files", which are passed to the compiler/linker to prevent commandline length issues such as the one you're experiencing. So if that is indeed the issue, yes, CMake will actually solve your problem.

Comment: The problem is most likely the `makefile` but we cannot be sure because the `makefile` is not posted.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem when using IAR's Eclipse plugin, but for me it was on the compilation step. I had so many include paths that we were overrunning the command length limit. My solution, and maybe it will help you, was to make sure everything built using relative paths instead of absolute paths. In my case, it was a matter of changing the include directories inside of the Eclipse project to specify them as relative paths. I'm not sure if you can accomplish the same thing with your makefile, but hopefully this might help.

Comment: I use relative paths for the compiler, but these lines:
OBJDIR=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
seem to translate the relative paths of .c files to absolute paths for the object files. I don't know how to change this

Comment: I don't know make well, but there are a lot of people here who do, so hopefully someone can help.